# _context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges(); returning {"Id":-2147482647} instead of actual values

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I use asp.net core, ef core version 5.0.
I have an entity called Project and an audit entity to track all entity changes.

> entity -- Project(table to store project details) and audit (table to store all audit trail changes)

```
 _context.SaveChanges() adds information to project table with the primarykey of the table Id (PK int autoincrement ) value being (15)


  _context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges(); detects all table changes but the primary key value instead of returning 15 its returning as {"Id":-2147482647}
```

any idea why its showing such a huge value of -2147482647 instead of actual value. Another row into the project table gets the id as -2147482648 instead of actual value 16. I guess its a temporary value.

any idea how to get original value?

Comment: Why are you doing this? It  won't return anything - `SaveChanges` persists all changes *and* updates database-generated database keys. `DetectChanges()` after `SaveChanges` won't find any changes

Comment: it is persisting changes, the problem is not that., during audit tracking instead of returning actual id value of 15 its returning 2147482647

Comment: [EF Core generates temporary IDs which are then replaced with the real IDs when SaveChanges is called.](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6147). You haven't posted any auditing code though. To find changes you'll have to check `ChangeTracker.Entries()` before calling `SaveChanges`. Or you could use the database's auditing features to ensure auditing works no matter what. In SQL Server you could use [change tracking](https://www.sqlshack.com/creating-a-sql-server-audit-using-sql-server-change-tracking/) (available in all versions and editions) to track all changes, including deletions

Comment: Another option would be temporal tables (in all *supported* versions and editions) which would not just keep old values but allow you to query the table at a specific time

Comment: Are you calling `DetectChanges` before `SaveChanges`? `DetectChanges` does not retrieve the actual PK values (it does not call database at all, just checks and updates the tracked entity states - mainly to detect modified and (to be) deleted items). The actual PK is available *only* after `SaveChanges`, that's it.